# How do I fix the error, "Model is structurally singular, error found sorting equations"

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica, jmodelica

This is one of the most common errors I receive when working with OpenModelica Software.

I already understand how this error is usually triggered, when system parameters are conflicting and disagree with one another.

I've already tried omitting system parameters that I've deemed not an necessity to my system however nothing seems to fix the error.

My system is already very simple to begin with. Currently, I'm working on a sub-assembly verification process in order to correctly build a working Rankine Power model. The sub assembly focuses on a (1) of (2) heat exchangers that would be used in a dual HX system incorporating a reheat process inbetween the High Pressure and Low Pressure turbines.

This sub assembly is trying to describe water coming from a pump at a condensed liquid state where it will travel through a heat exchanger "super heater" where it will change the state from a compressed liquid to a superheated vapor. This vapor will then be fed into the High Pressure turbine and return into a Pressure Sink.

I've already completed a hand calculated thermodynamic analysis of my system and know outlet temperatures and enthalpies. However, these outlet parameters are some of which I chose to remove for I felt I would let the system solve for them instead of telling it what it should calculate. Removing these values to solve the error did not work as well.

If you have any thoughts, advice or considerations please let me know! Below I've posted the code to what I have been working on. Thanks again!

CODE:

```
model HX_Pump_2_Superheater_2_HPTurbine

//Heat Exchanger - Steam entering HX (compressed liquid) --> Steam exiting 
HX (super heated vapor)//
//Steam Turbine - High Pressure Turbine and is (1) of (2) in series with one 
another. Exit pressure should be intermediate pressure level before being 
reheated and directed towards Low Pressure Turbine//

ThermoPower.PowerPlants.HRSG.Components.HE HX(
FluidPhaseStart = ThermoPower.Choices.FluidPhase.FluidPhases.Liquid, 
Tstartbar_G (displayUnit = "K") = 787.87, 
dpnom_F(displayUnit = "Pa") = 0, 
dpnom_G = 0, 
exchSurface_F = 4.739, 
exchSurface_G = 4.739, 
extSurfaceTub = 9.479, 
fluidNomFlowRate = 26.397, 
fluidNomPressure = 8e+06, 
fluidVol = 0.0296, 
gasNomFlowRate = 169.755, 
gasNomPressure = 101325, 
gasVol = 0.0296, 
lambda = 20, 
metalVol = 5, 
pstart_F = 8e+06, 
pstart_G = 101325, 
rhomcm = 1, 
rhonom_F(displayUnit = "kg/m3") = 0.6, 
rhonom_G(displayUnit = "kg/m3") = 0.33)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-1.9984e-15, 14}, extent 
= {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Gas.SinkPressure sinkPressure1(
redeclare package Medium = ThermoPower.Media.FlueGas, 
T = 106.86 + 273, 
p0 = 101325) annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {92, 14}, extent = {{-10, 
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Gas.SensT sensT1(
redeclare package Medium = ThermoPower.Media.FlueGas, 
allowFlowReversal = false) annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-50, 18}, extent = {{-10, 
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Gas.SensT sensT2(
redeclare package Medium = ThermoPower.Media.FlueGas, 
allowFlowReversal = false) annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {50, 18}, extent = {{-10, 
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Water.SinkPressure sinkPressure2(
redeclare package Medium = ThermoPower.Water.StandardWater, 
T = 165 + 273, 
h = 2536.2092e5, 
p0 = 7.0e5) annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {92, -60}, extent = {{-10, 
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Water.SensT sensT3(
redeclare package Medium = ThermoPower.Water.StandardWater) annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {4, 64}, extent = {{-10, 
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));

ThermoPower.Water.SensT sensT4(
redeclare package Medium = ThermoPower.Water.StandardWater, 
allowFlowReversal = false) annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {4, -32}, extent = {{-10, 
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));

inner ThermoPower.System system annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-90, 90}, extent = {{-10, 
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Gas.SourceMassFlow sourceMassFlow1(
redeclare package Medium = ThermoPower.Media.FlueGas, 
T = 514 + 273, 
p0 = 101325,
w0 = 169.755) annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-90, 14}, extent = {{-10, 
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Water.SourceMassFlow sourceMassFlow2(
redeclare package Medium = ThermoPower.Water.StandardWater, 
T = 42.88 + 273, 
h = 183.1e3, 
p0 = 80e5, 
use_T = true, 
w0 = 26.397) annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {2, 92}, extent = {{-10, 
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));

ThermoPower.Water.SteamTurbineStodola steamTurbineStodola1(
Kt = 0.01328, 
PRstart = 11.43, 
explicitIsentropicEnthalpy = false, 
pnom = 80.0e5, 
pout(fixed = false), 
w(fixed = false), 
wnom = 26.397, 
wstart = 26.397)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {12, -72}, extent = {{-14, 
-14}, {14, 14}}, rotation = 0)));

equation
connect(sensT2.outlet, sinkPressure1.flange) annotation(
Line(points = {{56, 14}, {82, 14}}, color = {159, 159, 223}));
connect(steamTurbineStodola1.outlet, sinkPressure2.flange) annotation(
Line(points = {{24, -60}, {82, -60}, {82, -60}, {82, -60}}, color = {0, 0, 
255}));
connect(sensT4.outlet, steamTurbineStodola1.inlet) annotation(
Line(points = {{0, -38}, {0, -38}, {0, -60}, {0, -60}}, color = {0, 0, 
255}));
connect(HX.waterOut, sensT4.inlet) annotation(
Line(points = {{0, -6}, {0, -26}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
connect(sourceMassFlow1.flange, sensT1.inlet) annotation(
Line(points = {{-80, 14}, {-56, 14}}, color = {159, 159, 223}));
connect(sensT3.outlet, HX.waterIn) annotation(
Line(points = {{0, 58}, {0, 58}, {0, 34}, {0, 34}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
connect(sourceMassFlow2.flange, sensT3.inlet) annotation(
Line(points = {{0, 82}, {0, 70}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
connect(HX.gasOut, sensT2.inlet) annotation(
Line(points = {{20, 14}, {44, 14}, {44, 14}, {44, 14}}, color = {159, 159, 
223}));
connect(sensT1.outlet, HX.gasIn) annotation(
Line(points = {{-44, 14}, {-20, 14}, {-20, 14}, {-20, 14}}, color = {159, 
159, 223}));
annotation(
uses(ThermoPower(version = "3.1"), Modelica(version = "3.2.3")));end 
HX_Pump_2_Superheater_2_HPTurbine;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message in Dymola says:

> The model HX_Pump_2_Superheater_2_HPTurbine is structurally singular.
>
> The problem is structurally singular for the element type Real.
>
> The number of scalar Real unknown elements are 93. The number of
>   scalar Real equation elements are 93.
>
> The following variables are considered as unknowns, but are not
>   appearing in the equations. steamTurbineStodola1.phi
>
> Part of the problem for Real elements is overdetermined. There are 1
>   scalar equations too many in the set: 
>   ...

The important part is that steamTurbineStodola1.phi does not appear in the equations. That is the angle of turbine shaft, and it indicates that the turbine-shaft is just "free floating".
Adding an inertia and connecting it to the shaft avoids that problem:

```
public
  Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Components.Inertia inertia
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{28,-82},{48,-62}})));
equation
connect(steamTurbineStodola1.shaft_b, inertia.flange_a)
    annotation (Line(points={{20.96,-72},{28,-72}}, color={0,0,0}));
```

but then there are other issues related to low pressure etc.

Obviously adding just an inertia with default inertia isn't the correct model - but I believe it indicates what to do.